# Laravel MySQL 8 duplicate foreign key constraint

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm working in a new Laravel 10 project running MySQL 8.0. I have two models: `Campaign` and `MarketingList`. Both models are owned by a `User`, but when trying to add a `constrained()` reference to `user_id` in each table I get the following error:

> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1826 Duplicate foreign key constraint name '1' (Connection: mysql, SQL: alter table `marketing_lists` add constraint `1` foreign key (`user_id`) references `users` (`id`))

It seems that MySQL can only have one or the other which isn't my desired outcome since I want to always link things back to a `User`. What am I missing to resolve this? Here's my two tables:

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        if (! Schema::hasTable('campaigns')) {
            Schema::create('campaigns', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->uuid('id')->primary();
                $table->foreignUuid('user_id')->constrained()->index();
                $table->string('name');
                $table->tinyInteger('priority')->default(100);
                $table->dateTime('send_at');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('campaigns');
    }
};
```

and...

```php
<?php

use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

return new class extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     */
    public function up(): void
    {
        if (! Schema::hasTable('marketing_lists')) {
            Schema::create('marketing_lists', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->uuid('id')->primary();
                $table->foreignUuid('user_id')->constrained()->index();
                $table->string('name');
                $table->timestamps();
            });
        }
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     */
    public function down(): void
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('marketing_lists');
    }
};
```

Comment: That's interesting... Why would it use the name `1` as the FK Constraint name? The `constrained()` method allows you to pass arguments to name it yourself: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints, like `constrained(indexName: 'marketing_lists_user_id_fk')` (or similar), but it's still odd that you'd need to...

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `->index()` as I believe `foreignUuid()` automatically adds an index, and you are attempting to add a second duplicate index resulting in the error you mentioned.

Comment: If an index exists that the foreign key can use, MySQL uses that index. It doesn't create a superfluous index.

Comment: Well after a bit of research we are both sort of right, this is one of those in-betweens. MySQL will automatically create an index on a constrained foreign key if the database engine is InnoDB. So the two keys are that it has to be `constrained` and also `InnoDB`. But thanks for highlighting that its not automatic. Time to go double-check a few projects lol.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, it looks like `constrained()` must come [after](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/migrations#foreign-key-constraints) other methods...

```php
$table->foreignUuid('user_id')->index()->constrained();
```

Forgot that!

Comment: Nice! Glad you got it sorted out! Seeing as this is simply a typo, probably best to delete this question though (but up to you; it'll likely be closed as such, but no harm either way)